# How to populate META and LINKS pagination on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I need help to populate this kind of pagination on laravel eloquent.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": 10,
    "total": 100
  },
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost/page[limit]=10&page[offset]=0",
    "last": "http://localhost/page[limit]=10&page[offset]=10",
    "next": "http://localhost/page[limit]=10&page[offset]=10",
    "prev": "null"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "checklists",
      "id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried this code on Laravel Eloquent.

```php
$data = Model::select('type','id')->paginate(10);
return response()->json(
    [
        'data' => $data
    ],200
);
```

But it shows different format, there is no META and LINKS schema on data populated.

```
{
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "type": "Mechanical Equipment Sales Representative",
                "id": 1
            }
       ],
        "first_page_url": "http://localhost?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 4,
        "last_page_url": "http://localhost?page=4",
        "next_page_url": "http://localhost?page=2",
        "path": "http://localhost",
        "per_page": 10,
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 10,
        "total": 39
    }
}
```

How to do that? Please help?

Comment: be more specific, show your tried code

Comment: I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use API resources: https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources#pagination

Create a collection resource:

```
php artisan make:resource ModelCollection
```

Use it in your controller:

```
$data = Model::select('type','id')->paginate(10);

return new ModelCollection($data);
```

For Lumen, create a `app/Http/Resources/ModelCollection.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ModelCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. How about doing this on lumen? There is no make:resource on it. Is there any manual step to create make:resource?

Comment: Thank you so much. I did this kind of format manually, till I got stuck how can pagination become separated from resource it self. Now I understand how easy doing it. Thank you, you save my time.

Comment: I have different cases with same model. Could you like to check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864032/how-to-get-property-of-model-on-paginate-resource