# How to get property of model on paginate resource

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display paginate resource on lumen using Resource.

I need this shown as below json result:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": 10,
    "total": 100
  },
  "links": {
    "first": "http://localhost/page[limit]=10&page[offset]=0",
    "last": "http://localhost/page[limit]=10&page[offset]=10",
    "next": "http://localhost/page[limit]=10&page[offset]=10",
    "prev": "null"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "items",
      "id": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my **controller**:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Item\Eloquent\ItemModel as ItemModel;
use App\Http\Resources\ItemsResource;

public function completeitems(Request $request)
{
    $res    = ItemModel::paginate();
    return new ItemsResource($res);
}
?>
```

This is my **ItemResource**:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ItemsResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'type'          => 'items',
            'id'            => $this->id
        ];
    }
}
```

From my code the result is:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id
```

I have tried this many time and google the error but a bit confuse.
How to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: `'type'          => item',` quote missing correct that

Comment: Ups! My mistake, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

To have meta data, and link data, you need to use **Resource Collections**:

```
php artisan make:resource ItemCollection
```

More information you can get from here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried using ResouceCollection but it only show data collection, and I want to customize each property before shown as resource, hot to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `collection()` method to return multiple models:

```
public function completeitems(Request $request)
{
    $res    = ItemModel::paginate();
    return ItemsResource::collection($res);
}
```